# Clone the sibling project

Tags: git, github

By curiosity, I checked the source code of [supertux](https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux), located on GitHub, and cloned it (`git clone https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux.git`).

After the clone operation, I noticed that the `data` and `translation` folders are empty. When I check the GitHub page, they're both some kind of redirection to sibling projects under the same organization.

I couldn't find any way to properly clone the two empty sibling projects.

What is that and how do I clone everything in a minimal amount of commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project has submodules. Use **--recursive** option for full clone.
`git clone --recursive https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux.git`

Or after cloning:

`git submodule init`
`git submodule update`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that git had submodules like that. I took a look at the documentation and it seems really powerful! Thank you for showing me that ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: I give you +1 for being first with an appropriate answer, but the other one is more complete. Sorry.